# Is there any file pdf version which allow for automatic(or manual) addition of http source of document?

Tags: pdf, usability

Is there any pdf version which allow for automatic(or manual) addition of http source of document ?

Scenarion of this problem from user side looks like that :

1. I found disire document in pdf format on web.
2. I save it.
3. In a few months I open this document and I wish to find the web page where I've found it.

It would be nice to have somewhere address of that file, of course it could be manually written in soe text file, but usually there are problems with copy+paste of pdf documents titles.

Answer (score 4):

If you can modify your PDF files before sending them to the browser, then there are several places where you could put the URL where the document came from:

1. You could use a node in the "logical structure" tree (chapter 14 part 7 of the [PDF reference document](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)). This tree will show up in Acrobat Reader in the "Model Tree" tab.
2. You could add a hyperlink annotation to the top or bottom of each page, or the first page, or in a new page that you can add at the beginning or at the end of the file. I personally think this is the best approach since the link will be click-able.
3. You could add a button field on a page that fires a GoTo action that is linked to the source URL. Actions are explained in chapter 12 - Interactive Features of the PDF reference document.
4. You could add a bookmark(outline) that points to a named destination that is linked to the source URL. Named Destinations are also explained in chapter 12. This approach can also be used with just one click, and it is possible to hide the bookmarks tab if we will not use it.
5. You could add it as a Document property as [@Bobrovsky said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11884388/501196).

Comment: +1 ... but the chapter numbers you mention don't match the PDF spec version you linked to. (For example, interactive features are dealt with in chapter 12 of that link, not 8.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, it seems I have to update my offline copy of the file.

Answer (score 2):

PDF allows you to add custom values to document information dictionary (see 14.3.3, "Document Information Dictionary" in PDF Reference). You might put your URL there. Adobe Reader will show custom values in Document Properties dialog on the Advanced tab.

Starting from PDF 1.4 (Acrobat 5x and later) you might add URL to XMP Metadata stream referenced from document catalog (see 14.3 Metadata in PDF Reference). Adobe Reader will show metadata properties too if you put them in Custom scheme.

Acrobat Professional could be used to add custom values or XMP metadata. Almost any PDF library that can open and save PDFs could be used for the task too.

I think there is no other places *in* a PDF document that you can use to store your information.

[PDF Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)